# Can someone spot why my React array filtering isn't working?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm wanting to do something fairly simple in needing to filter a number of products in my React project.  The array of filters (an array of strings) is stored in State. By default the array contains ["All"] until another filter is clicked and this is replaced by that filter name. I can add filter strings okay to the array but in removing them they don't seem to be removed from the array.

I am making a copy of the array to avoid mutation but not sure if I'm doing it right? I had it working without making a copy but then wanted to test if the array was empty. As the page hadn't rendered yet I was getting the old value of the array. I wasn't sure of the best way to approach it? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
function FilterGroup({ filterData }) {
 const [ filtersApplied, setFiltersApplied] = useState(["All"]);
 const filterListItemElements = filterData.map((el, index) => (
   <button
     className={`text-white ${filtersApplied.includes(el) ? '' : 'text-opacity-30 hover:text-opacity-70'}  pl-0.5 text-xs block w-full cursor-pointer`}
     key={index}
     onClick={() => handleFilterClick(el)}
     // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unknown-property
     aria-pressed={filtersApplied.includes(el)}
   >
     {el}
   </button>
 ));

 function handleFilterClick(val) {
   if (!filtersApplied.includes(val)) {
     // if item not already in the array

     if (val === "All") {
       // delete contents of Array and replace with "All"
       setFiltersApplied(["All"]);
     } else {
       // first remove "All" from Array if currently in there
       setFiltersApplied(
         filtersApplied.filter(name => name !== "All")
       );
       // now add the new item
       setFiltersApplied((filtersApplied) => [...filtersApplied, val]);
     }
   } else {

     // item already in Array so remove

     if(val === "All") return
    
     let tempArray = [...filtersApplied]
     tempArray.filter(name => name !== val)

      // now check if there are no longer any filters as will need to change Array back to "All"
     if(tempArray.length === 0) tempArray = ["All"]
     
     setFiltersApplied(tempArray);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleFilterClick` function, you're doing a good job of avoiding direct mutation of the `filtersApplied` array. However, there is a small mistake in your code that might lead to unexpected behavior.

In the **else** block, you're creating a copy of `filtersApplied` and filtering out the value that needs to be removed. However, you're not updating the state with the new array. Instead, you're updating the state with the original `filtersApplied` array. This is because the `filter` method does not mutate the original array, but returns a new array. You need to capture this new array and update the state with it.

I modify the part code to this;

```
let tempArray = [...filtersApplied]
tempArray = tempArray.filter(name => name !== val)

// now check if there are no longer any filters as will need to change Array back to "All"
if(tempArray.length === 0) tempArray = ["All"]

setFiltersApplied(tempArray);
```

As you see, `tempArray` is updated with the new array returned by the `filter` method. Then, the state is updated with this new array. This ensures that the state is always updated with a new array, avoiding direct mutation of the stater.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe that it was something so simple that I was not capturing the array. It seems obvious now!  I really appreciate your help. I've modified the code slightly following the advice of @astr

Answer (score 2):

`tempArray.filter(name => name !== val)` does not mutate the array  - it returns a filtered array. So what you probably want is `const filteredArray = tempArray.filter(name => name !== val)` and then continue the check on `filteredArray`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. @KeyboardCompanion helped me see the obvious but I can see that there was no need to copy array first now so appreciate you pointing that out.

I had to change the const declaration to let as I was modifying the array when checking if my array was empty. So I now have

`let filteredArray = filtersApplied.filter(name => name !== val)

       // now check if there are no longer any filters as will need to change Array back to "All"
      if(filteredArray.length === 0) filteredArray = ["All"]
      
      setFiltersApplied(filteredArray);`